# Using Zipf's law to select top K ngrams?

Tags: text-mining, zipf

Lets say we extract all the ngrams (unigrams, bigrams, trigrams) along with their frequency from a text. Now if we want to select say some Top K ngrams, is there a way to estimate a good value of K using Zipf's law ?
e.g. if Ngrams are -> w1:10, w2:9, w3:9, w4:8, w5:5, w6:3, w7:1, w8:1, w9:1, w10:1.
Here are Ngrams are w1,w2,w3 etc and numbers after them are their frequencies.
Ideally we would like to have K here as 5 or 6.
Is there a way to estimate K using Zipf's law ?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking for here. When you say "Ideally we would like to have K here as 5 or 6...", for example, how are you arriving at that? What property do you want $K$ to satisfy?

Comment: Well, I read that the ngram frequency distribution actually follows Zipf's law and in Zipf's distibution we have a long tail which consist of less important ngrams. So, K is basically an estimate of start of long tail, so that we can select the top K ngrams which are above the long tail and hence should be more important.

Comment: Ok. The Zipf distribution itself encodes no such concept or parameter. There are other related distributions that might. On the other hand, I think there is more of a practical question lurking here and that's what I'd like to coax out into the open.

Comment: One question that sort of seems natural and related might be: Given a large sample of text, at what $K$ (as a function of corpus size) can I divide the ngrams into two sets: one that contains the top $K$ most common words and the other being "the rest"? But, you might be interested more in feature extraction or something else applied to a *particular* corpus. Can you clarify?

Comment: hmm.. well your question is exactly the problem that I was referring to. Dividing Ngrams into two sets based on just frequency counts. Its basically to decide a cutoff frequency below which n grams might not be that useful.

Comment: No, snow_leopard, it's a fundamentally different question, though the difference may seem subtle on first reading (and I may not have worded it clearly enough to make the distinction as apparent as it could be).